# Is there any method to make compare in keras layers?

Tags: keras, theano

I want to compare two numbers in keras model. The input of this layer is a tensorvariable and this layer compare this tensorvariable with a constant. Then it will return 0 or 1.
Is there any method? I tried to find a function in theano to do this job but failed.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the functions in [keras backend](https://keras.io/backend/)

```
import keras.backend as K
```

What you need is one of these: *K.equal, K.greater, K.greater_equal, etc.*

You can use a `Lambda` layer for that:

```
Lambda(lambda x: K.cast(K.greater_equal(x,constant),'float32'),output_shape=sameAsInputShape)
```